# mod_python using wrong version

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

So redhat uses python 2.4 and I need to upgrade to python 2.6 (so I did an altinstall) does anybody know how to install mod_python? (I am installing from source.) This is what I ran:

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.6
make
make install
```

But according to a stack trace I get mod_python is still using python 2.4 (which is the default for redhat 4) I need it to use 2.6. I'm still a newbie to this... any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

N.B.: I can't use wsgi because my server hosts some other websites that relies on mod_pyhton and if I install both I heard bad things happen (segfaults, deadlocks etc...) It would be I ideal if I could install it under a different name (say mod_python2.6) but I don't know if that is even possible.
I also tried the Chris Lea's repository but it's missing mod_pyhton for redhat 4 64 bit

Comment: What is this "pyhton" of which you speak?

Comment: As you are preparing to stake your applications' future on top of mod_python, just something to keep in mind:

Mod_Python is officially dead. 

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html

This might be time to move other web apps to wsgi-based infrastructure, or to stand-alone python-based web servers (twisted, paste,tornado etc) and do the reverse proxy with something like nginx.

Comment: Holly smokes it died last week! thanks for informing me! I wish I could up-vote comments... I guess newbies can't do it...